# Monge-Kantorovich duality with a $\{0,1\}$ cost function

Tags: pr.probability, duality, optimal-transportation

Consider the usual Monge-Kantorovich transportation problem where $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on $X$ and $Y$, and $c:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{+\infty \}$ is a lower semi-continuous cost function.  The Kantorovich duality theorem states that the transportation cost between $\mu$ and $\nu$ is equal to the supremum of $$\int_X \varphi~ d\mu +\int_Y \psi~ d\nu $$ over all $L_1$ functions $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$  such that  $\varphi(x)+\psi(y)\leq c(x,y)$ for $d \mu$-almost all $x\in X$ and $d \nu$-almost all $y\in Y$.

My question is:  if $c(x,y)\in \{0,1\}$ for all $x$ and $y$, and for each $x$ there exists $y_1,y_2$ such that $c(x,y_1)=0$ and $c(x,y_2)=1$ (and similarly for each $y$ there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that the equivalent condition holds) does it follow that there exists a solution (or "almost exists" a solution) where $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ only take values in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$?  Finite dimensional experiments with linear programs suggest that the answer is "yes" but I cannot tell if they extend to the general setting.

UPDATE:  I added additional conditions about $c$, which guarantees that we can find solutions such that $0\leq\varphi\leq1$ and $-1\leq \psi \leq 0$.  This is because we can shift $\varphi$ and $\psi$ such that $\sup_x \varphi(x)=1$, which guarantees that $\psi(y)\geq-1$.  Furthermore, it must always be true that $\psi(y)\leq 0$ because otherwise there would exist $x,y$ such that $\varphi(x) + \psi(y) > 1$.  This in turn guarantees that we can always assume that $\varphi(x)\geq 0$ as well.

Comment: Two quick comments: First, I posted a wrong answer earlier where I simply messed up a detail, sorry! Second should "$\varphi(x) + \psi(y) \leq c(x, y)$ for almost all ..." be instead pointwise (since no measure on the product space is given)?

Comment: Thanks @Steve!  I made a correction regarding your second comment.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of optimal transport says that any measure on the product space that has its support in the c-superdifferential of a c-concave function is optimal for it's marginals. So you can try to build a counterexample by finding a phi which has other values than 1, 0, -1 and which is also c-concave.

Comment: I think Steve meant that the inequality should hold everywhere (aren't the potentials continuous functions anyway?).

Comment: @Dirk yes the theorem I'm looking at (Theorem 1.3 of Villani's "Topics in Optimal Transporation") says that you can assume WLOG that the potentials are continuous, but we're taking a supremum as opposed to a maximum.  I'm updating the question with some additional findings now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strong Kantorovich duality, i.e. the existence of dual solutions, holds whenever $c$ is lower semicontinuous and **real-valued**, and the optimal coupling has finite cost, see Theorem 5.10(ii) in Villani "Optimal Transport old and new". In contrast, for the weak duality ("$\inf = \sup$") it suffices to assume $c$ is lower semicontinuous.

To prove 5.10(ii) one constructs an explicit $c$-concave function $\varphi$ that is finite-valued on the support of $\mu$, see formula (5.17). Beware of signs! Villani is looking at $c$-convex functions and you at $c$-concave functions.

To answer the "value part" of the question: the values of $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are only important on the support of $\mu$ and resp. $\nu$. Everywhere else you may choose them to be $-\infty$ (loosing $c$-concavity). Now some cases: If the optimal coupling $\pi$ has cost $1$ then for all $(x,y),(x',y') \in \Gamma := \operatorname{supp}\pi$ it holds $c(x,y')=1$ as otherwise $c(x',y)+c(x,y') < 2 = c(x,y)+c(x',y')$ violating $c$-cyclic monotonicty. Thus $\varphi \equiv 0 \equiv \psi-1$ is a dual solution to the problem. A similar case happens if the cost is $0$ on $\operatorname{supp}\mu \times \operatorname{supp}\nu$. For the last case, pick $(x_0,y_0) \in \Gamma$ with $c(x_0,y_0)=0$ and do the standard construction to get an *integer-valued* $c$-concave $\varphi$ with $\varphi(x_0)=0$. Observe if $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in \Gamma$ then

\begin{align*}
\varphi(x_{1}) + \psi(x_1) & = c(x_{1},x_{1})\\
\varphi(x_{2}) + \psi(x_2) & = c(x_{2},x_{2}).
\end{align*}

Subtracting this from $\varphi+\psi\le c$ applied to the couples $(x_1.y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$ gives
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x_{2})-\varphi(x_{1}) & \le c(x_{2},y_{1})-c(x_{1},x_{1})\\
\varphi(x_{1})-\varphi(x_{2}) & \le c(x_{1},y_{2})-c(x_{2},y_{2}).
\end{align*}
The right hand side has values in $\{-1,0,1\}$. 
Since $\varphi(x_0)=0$ the function $\varphi$ has values in the same set. Since $1-(-1)=2$, it must have values either in $\{0,1\}$ or in $\{-1,0\}$. A similar argument as above then shows that $\psi$ needs have values in $\{-1,0\}$ or $\{0,1\}$.

Note if $c$ is not real-valued then there may not be any dual solutions between certain measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, see the [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04393) of S. Suhr and me on Lorentzian cost function, more explicitly Section 3.1.

Comment: How does this answer the question (which asks if there are optimal potentials with taking only specific values )?

Comment: Since the value question was "already" answered in the question itself, I didn't include it. Now there is a short statement.

Comment: Could you give a reference that the standard construction shows that $\varphi$ is either identically $0$ or $0$ and somewhere $1$?  I do not see how that follows from (5.17) in "Optimal transport old and new".

Comment: I changed to a direct argument.

Comment: Sorry but I am still having trouble with the very last step -- how do the inequalities on $\varphi(x_1)-\varphi(x_2)$ and so forth, combined with the fact that $\varphi(x_0)=0$, lead to the desired conclusion?

Comment: I am *really* sorry that I keep having trouble with this, but I am still unclear on how the two inequalities lead one to conclude that "The left hand side has values in $\{-1,0,1\}$".  Am I supposed to plug in $x_0,y_0$ for one of the $x_i,y_i$'s?  For example, if $c(x_2,y_1) =1$ and $c(x_1,y_2) = c(x_1,y_1) = c(x_2,y_2)=0$, then the inequalities say that $-1 \leq \varphi(x_1)-\varphi(x_2) \leq 0$, but I don't understand why they have to actually take one of those values.

Comment: Was the right hand side. Was just a typo. This is true as c has values 0 or 1 so the difference can have at most the mentioned three values. The inequality then shows that the oscillation of phi is at most 1. Knowing phi at x0 is 0 gives the claims.

Comment: That certainly helps, but I'm stuck on the fact that "oscillation of $\varphi$ is AT MOST 1" gives us that the oscillation of $\varphi$ is EQUAL to 1, if at all -- e.g., how does this exclude the possibility that $\varphi(x_1)=0.5$?

Comment: Ah, this follows from the construction that the sum and difference of c evaluated at different couples is an integer. Thus phi is integer-values.

Comment: I am sure that I will smack myself in the forehead once this sinks in, but for the example I gave before with $c(x_2,y_1)=1$ and $c(x_1,y_2) = c(x_1,y_1) = c(x_2,y_2)=0$, these inequalities say that $-1 \leq \varphi(x_1)-\varphi(x_2) \leq 0$.  What additional information do I need in order to conclude that one of these inequalities is tight?  If I plug in, say, $x_2=x_0$ and $y_2 = y_0$, then I am left with $-1 \leq \varphi(x_1) \leq 0$.

Comment: Well, a supermizer $\varphi$ would like to make the objective as large as possible, so you would always want  $\varphi(x_1)$ as large as possible (as long as the constraint stays satisfied).

Comment: I don’t understand the problem as the argument does not claim any sharpness. Maybe it helps to clarify the notation:  the constant function equal to 0 has values in $\{0,1\}$. The example given in your comment just verifies that $\varphi$ has values in $\{-1,0\}$.

Comment: The example in my comment shows that we can conclude that $\varphi(x_1)\in [-1,0]$, but I want to prove that in fact $\varphi(x_1)\in \{-1,0\}$, i.e. that $\varphi(x_1)$ must take on one of those two values.  As far as I am aware, this is the standard notation for invervals versus discrete sets.

Comment: In the answer I added that phi is integer-valued. This follows from formula (5.17) in Villani’s book and the assumption that c is integer-valued. I don’t claim that a given dual solution is integer-valued. Most likely it is possible to glue together two solutions. One that is constant and another one that has exactly oscillation equal to 1. In a case i could imagine (I don’t have time to construct such an example), there might be a dual solution that has values 0,0.5 and 1.

Comment: Ah, so the standard construction for $\varphi$ in Villani's book will automatically result in this fact.  So, I just have to read those details more carefully to understand this.  Thanks!